# How to share slightly different structs between two go apps?

Tags: go, architecture

I'm facing a big architecture issue in my go project.

1. I have an API that uses structures that come from a MongoDB databases. That means I'm using the `database.ObjectID` data type in order to store my IDs. For example, here is how I would store an user in the API :

```
type User struct {
    Id       primitive.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Username string
    Tag      int
}
```

2. The front app is also made in go and uses the same structures because it obviously takes its data from the API. BUT it's not very convenient for the front app to use this `primitive.ObjectID` data type : the parsing to string is not automatic and it's a bit difficult to manipulate. So from the app front point of view, the data structure would more likely look like this :

```
type User struct {
    Id       string
    Username string
    Tag      int
}
```

Now in order not to repeat too much code, i would like to re-use those structures from one project to the other with a third party module i would create, without having to write them all twice (one version with `string`, the other with `primitive.ObjectId`).

How can I do ?

Comment: this is matter of opinion, anyway in my opinion you shouldn't couple the front-end and the database layers this tightly. Keep the structs separated.

Comment: The problem is, in go the syntax to create `struct`'s is so heavy and without inheritance so that would really mean adding thousands of lines... :/

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `ID` type that is equal to `interface{}`. Then use this `ID` type, casting to `primitive.ObjectID` or `string` when needed. (See example below)

```
type User struct {
    ID ID `bson:"_id"`
}

type ID = interface{}

func main() {
    u := User{
        ID: primitive.NewObjectID(),
    }

    oid := u.ID.(primitive.ObjectID) // Cast to "primitive.ObjectID"

    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(oid)) // primitive.ObjectID
}
```

Comment: The thing is, when you cast a primitive.ObjectID to string, it looks like this : `ObjectId("abcdef1234567890abcdef")`, making it totally unusable

Comment: When casting the `_id` field (ObjectID) to a string (on the results from MongoDB), it appears to equal `abcdef1234567890abcdef`

Comment: This will result in re-creating a big part of the parsing mechanism, but that's an acceptable solution.

Comment: Your other option is to use ‘primitive.ObjectID’ and the type and use the built in methods to get it as a string on the front end

Comment: I considered this, but since I'm using the go templating engine, such practice will result in having raw 'ObjectId("abcdef1234567890abcdef")' printed on the page instead of just 'abcdef1234567890abcdef'.